# form_for Update Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code which I would like to update the particular object in the database. For some reason however this function will not display. Based on the log reports I am getting back nothing is wrong. Information outside of the code block is returned fine.

```
<% form_for (@person), :url => {:controller => "persons", :action => "update" } do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :name, "Name" %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.label :score, "Score" %>
        <%= f.text_field :score %>
  <%= f.submit("Update") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should remove the parenthesis around (@person) as they're just confusing and have no effect. It might look like there's only one argument to form_for but the hash passed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `<%= form_for ...` instead of `<% form_for ...` (it's all in that equal sign)